# org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '`'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying use the following following query using JPARepository but it is throwing

> org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '`' "

exception.

Here is the named query I have:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "shift_planner.fetchThisWeekShiftDetails",
         query = 
         "SELECT r.resouce_name,s.shift_name,sp.plan_date 
          FROM elias.shift_planner sp, elias.resources r, elias.shifts s 
          WHERE sp.resource_id=r.resource_id and sp.shift_id=s.shift_id 
           AND YEARWEEK(`plan_date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)"
)
```

Comment: what editor you are using, check for the encoding in editor

Comment: I'm using eclipse.

Comment: Aphostropy is causing issue for colmn plandate

Comment: You think that "query" is JPQL? It has various functions that are not valid in JPQL.

Comment: JPQL uses entity names and entity field property/names. Not schema, table and column names. It's not the same language as SQL. If it as, it would be named SQL, not JPQL.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide me this query in jpql. I couldn't able to find that's why I choose native sql.

Answer (score 7):

atlast I found the solution, I have enabled nativeQuery and return type change to Object[].

```
@Query( value="SELECT resouce_name,shift_name,plan_date FROM   elias.shift_planner sp, elias.resources r, elias.shifts s WHERE  sp.resource_id=r.resource_id and sp.shift_id=s.shift_id and YEARWEEK(`plan_date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)order by plan_date",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object[]> fetchThisWeekShiftDetails();
```